# Switching from two monitors to one

Tags: multiple-monitors

I had two monitors and while using 3DSMax I had my Viewport opened on one monitor and all my drop-down tabs on the other (such as "Material Editor" , ... ). But I have just recently moved and only brought with me one monitor so now I can't access the drop-down tabs.
How do I go about resolving the issus.
Thank you

Comment: what os are you on? mac, windows, linux

Answer (score 1):

If the window is simply out of view, you can use the move trick:

- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to the window or click it in the taskbar to give it focus
- Right click on it's taskbar entry and select **move**
- Press any one of the arrow keys on the keyboard, and then move your mouse to have the window pop back onto the screen.

If you are trying to increase functionality with this program that is spanning over 1 monitor, you may be interested in [360desktop](http://www.360desktop.com/):

[image]

Comment: How do I make those keyboard key icons?

Comment: is there something like 460 desktop, but for the mac?

Answer (score 1):

alt+space brings up the menu you get when you right-click one of the top bars, then M is for move.

If you can alt+tab to it, then alt+space, M, then hold the RIGHT or LEFT key to move it back into view.